# How to change URL hash on scroll>

Tags: jquery, scroll

I was wondering how I can change the hash in my URL bar while scrolling to another section. I used the following code to change the menu item class of the visible section in the viewport:

function setActiveListElements(event){
        // Get the offset of the window from the top of page
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();

```
    $('#primary-navwrapper li a[href^="#"]').each(function() { 
        var anchorId = $(this);
        var target = $(anchorId.attr("href"));
        //console.log(target);

        var offsetTop = target.position().top - offset;

        if (target.length > 0) {

            if (target.position().top - offset <= windowPos && (target.position().top + target.height() + offset ) > windowPos) {
                $('#primary-navwrapper li a').removeClass("current");
                anchorId.addClass("current");
            }
        }           

    });

}
```

I have already used a code to update the hash, when the user clicks on a menu item, but doesn’t know how to integrate it inside above code:

$('#primary-navwrapper li, .list-of-links li').find('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event) { 
        // Prevent from default action to intitiate
        event.preventDefault();

```
    $('#primary-navwrapper li a').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");

    var anchorId = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(anchorId).offset().top - offset;         
    //console.log(target);

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = anchorId;        
    });

});
```

In above code I used: `window.location.hash = anchorId;`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the following code?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var hashString = '#yourHashString'
    history.pushState('','', hashString);
});
```

Comment: I have update the answer. But with above sample, you should have an hard coded hashID or not?

Comment: Maybe you missed the anchortag (#) before the anchorid? location.hash = '#myhash';